# What is the meaning of “on the railway”?

Tags: england-and-wales, transportation, public-transport

Rule 6 of the TfL Railway Byelaws provide in several contexts for behaviour that shall not be committed “on the railway.”

What here is the scope of “the railway”? Does it include station platforms? Concourses? Ticket halls? Or only the trains themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Railway" means ([s. 28; pp. 13–14](https://content.tfl.gov.uk/railway-byelaws.pdf#page=13)):

> (a) the railways and railway premises of Transport for London and any of its
> subsidiaries including any train, other vehicle, station, depot, track and any
> associated equipment; and
>
> (b) any train, or other vehicle and any associated equipment which is for the time being used by a person or body for the purposes of providing railway services under an agreement with Transport for London or any of its subsidiaries;